# Katalon Studio throw error message during exit

Tags: exception, katalon-studio

I get error message when exit Katalon Studio. I use Windows 8.1 and Katalon Studio 5.9.1.

[image: katalon error message]

Content of log file:

```
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access

!MESSAGE Job found still running after platform shutdown. Jobs should be canceled by the plugin that scheduled them during shutdown: org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.TaskBarProgressManager$2
```

Comment: Happens in Windows 10 with KS 5.9.0 and 5.9.1.

Comment: This is a bug reported to [Katalon Studio development team](https://forum.katalon.com/discussion/10458/i-keep-getting-error-when-closing-katalon-studio-last-one-after-update-wiped-some-progress).

Comment: @MateMrše : I haven't seen this error in earlier versions, just in this one.